# document.getElementById / Event Javascript do not work in browsers others than IE9

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with forcing my JS to work under IE8/Mozilla, but without no luck.
I need to have a JavaScript which which will copy data from excel (a column of single rows with values) into textboxes (textbox1, textbox2,...) in html page. I have written JS script, which works in IE9. But not in IE8 or Mozilla.
The possible problem is that `document.getElementById` is null...

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Below is the code of the html page with js. Thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org     /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
            </div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </form>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            //// javascript is used in order to paste multiple lines data into textboxes
            var textbox_id = 0;
            var clipboard;

            //// count number of textboxes on the page with ReadOnly=false property               
            var count_input_txtbox = 0; 
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var cpt = 0; cpt < inputs.length; cpt++)
                if (inputs[cpt].type == 'text' && inputs[cpt].id.substring(0, 7) == 'TextBox')
                    { count_input_txtbox++ };

            function processEvent(oEvent) {
                textbox_id = (oEvent.target || oEvent.srcElement).id.substring(7,(oEvent.target || oEvent.srcElement).id.length);
                clip_board = clipboardData.getData('text');
                k = textbox_id;
                clip_board = clip_board.replace('\n', '\r');

                ///clear text of target textbox
                document.getElementById('TextBox' + k).value = ''

                for (var j = 0; j < clip_board.length; j++) {
                    if ((k <= count_input_txtbox) && (clip_board.substring(j, j + 1) != '\r')) {
                        document.getElementById('TextBox' + k).value = document.getElementById('TextBox' + k).value + clip_board.substring(j, j + 1)
                    } else {
                        j = j + 1;
                        k++;
                        document.getElementById('TextBox' + k).value = ''
                    };
                };
            };

            //execute function processEvent onpaste
            // In case browser is not IE9
            if (!window.addEventListener)
                { window.attachEvent("onpaste", processEvent); }
            else
                // In case browser is IE9
                { window.addEventListener("paste", processEvent, false); }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting the correct values in `k`? One suggestion I'd make is about brackets (`{}`): Never leave them out like you did for the `for (var cpt`. And put the opening bracket behind the `for / if / else` etc statements, and the closing one on a new line instead of at the end of the line. That should make your code more readable, ike it is in the `processEvent` function.

Comment: I would suggest to use jquery for those kind of things. Jquery allows you to get elements from the page without being dependant on the browser (Jquery does that for you). document.getElementById("myid") becomes $("#myid") for example

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use asp:TextBox. It's proprietary MS code. Better use `input` tag. See the refined code below.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        //// javascript is used in order to paste multiple lines data into textboxes
        var textbox_id = 0;
        var clipboard;

        //// count number of textboxes on the page with ReadOnly=false property               
        var count_input_txtbox = 0; 
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var cpt = 0; cpt < inputs.length; cpt++)
            if (inputs[cpt].type == 'text' && inputs[cpt].id.substring(0, 7) == 'TextBox')
                { count_input_txtbox++ };

        function processEvent(oEvent) {
            textbox_id = (oEvent.target || oEvent.srcElement).id.substring(7,(oEvent.target || oEvent.srcElement).id.length);
            clip_board = clipboardData.getData('text');
            k = textbox_id;
            clip_board = clip_board.replace('\n', '\r');

            ///clear text of target textbox
            document.getElementById('TextBox' + k).value = ''

            for (var j = 0; j < clip_board.length; j++) {
                if ((k <= count_input_txtbox) && (clip_board.substring(j, j + 1) != '\r')) {
                    document.getElementById('TextBox' + k).value = document.getElementById('TextBox' + k).value + clip_board.substring(j, j + 1)
                } else {
                    j = j + 1;
                    k++;
                    document.getElementById('TextBox' + k).value = ''
                };
            };
        };

        //execute function processEvent onpaste
        // In case browser is not IE9
        if (!window.addEventListener)
            { window.attachEvent("onpaste", processEvent); }
        else
            // In case browser is IE9
            { window.addEventListener("paste", processEvent, false); }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be `<asp:TextBox...>` tag.

Do you get any textboxes in Firefox with it? How does the HTML-code look like in firefox and how in IE? (Right click on the website and "show sorcecode" or use firebug plugin.)

If you can use input tag, I have testet an example which works with IE and Firefox:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="text" ID="TextBox1">
        <br />
        <input type="text" ID="TextBox2">
        <br />
        <input type="text" ID="TextBox3">
    </form>

    <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="test">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            ///clear text of target textbox
            document.getElementById('TextBox' + 1).value = ''
            document.getElementById('TextBox' + 2).value = ''
            document.getElementById('TextBox' + 3).value = ''
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, You are right:document.getElementById works. The problem seems to be in another block of the code. window.attachEvent doesn't work...